Dash DCC button doesn't run Python script on live deployement
For automated testing purposes I have created a framework for deploying tests automatically.
This is integrated on a seperate server using the task scheduler. This works fine. However, I want to give people the opportunity to deploy a test mannualy, by using a Dash dashboard with buttons for deploying the tests.
The problem I encounter is that when I deploy the dabo locally via Jupyter, the scripts behind the buttons are deployed nicely, by using this code...:
def deploy_test_scl(n_clicks):
    # Don't run unless the button has been pressed...
    if n_clicks is None:

        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        os.chdir('<path_to_file>')
        call(["python", "main.py"])
        return  "tests are finished, see Power BI for the results"

...resulting in a visible loading element which stops when the tests are fully run, returning the message.
However, when I apply this code in the app.py file and the dabo is deployed via IIS manager, the code won't run and the script is not called. Even when I comment the call function and set only the return function, nothing will appear.
I have also tried the python 'subprocess' package, which doesn't work either.
Other neccessary information(?):

The deployement of the website (app.py), is a the inetpub/wwwroot directory.
the website is deployed via the IIS manager by using the FASTCGI module.
the fastcgi.py file is created within a virtual environment and placed in the wwwroot directory.

The only issue I can think of is to elevate the privileges to admin, but I am not sure. Furthermore, I have no other ideas which could cause the problem of not running the main.py script for deploying the tests, or even returning the text.
Can someone point me in the right direction why the python script is not called and thereby run?

For Python developers, learning HttpPlatformHandler becomes very important. Because Microsoft no longer recommends FastCGI, this is no longer the correct way to host Python web applications on IIS. You can try switching to HttpPlatformHandler.
